# Serializing an object to JSON in which the type is not known

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, serialization

I have a small program that contains two classes at the moment. On of the classes contains my application entry point and handles arguments from the commandline on startup, the other class contains options that I need to be serialized into a JSON format and then deserialized later on.

**The issue:** In my primary class, the class containing the entry point, I would like to create a generic method to serialize any object I throw at it to a JSON file. It looks like this:

```
public string Serialize(Object obj)
{
    JsonSerializerOptions o = new JsonSerializerOptions();
    o.WriteIndented = true;

    return JsonSerializer.Serialize((obj, o));
}
```

When I use "Object obj" as the argument it just creates a JSON file containing "{}"
However, when I write it like this and specify the object type (in this case "Settings" because that is the class I need serialized at the moment) it populates the fields with the information as expected.

```
public string Serialize(Settings so)
{
    JsonSerializerOptions o = new JsonSerializerOptions();
    o.WriteIndented = true;

    return JsonSerializer.Serialize((so, o));
}
```

I would like to be able to pass it any type of object and have it serialize it properly. This way I don't have to write 3 or 4 methods specifiying exactly which type of object it will be receiving to serialize each class (i.e Settings, DebugInfo, so on..)

Can anyone show me the easiest way to do this? I have tried multiple different overrides and just can't seem to get it to work. Its always an empty JSON file, unless I specify in the arguments exactly which class it is receiving.

I am using DotNet Core 3.1 and the namespaces

```
System.Text.Json;
System.Text.Json.Serialization;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your method generic:

```cs
public string Serialize<T>(T obj)
{
    JsonSerializerOptions o = new JsonSerializerOptions();
    o.WriteIndented = true;

    return JsonSerializer.Serialize<T>((obj, o));
}
```